# split a file based on string

Tags: python

I am trying to split one big file into individual entries. Each entry ends with the character “//”. So when I try to use

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os   
uniprotFile=open("UNIPROT-data.txt") #read original alignment file  
uniprotFileContent=uniprotFile.read() 
uniprotFileList=uniprotFileContent.split("//")
for items in uniprotFileList:
        seqInfoFile=open('%s.dat'%items[5:14],'w')
        seqInfoFile.write(str(items))
```

But I realised that there is another string with “//“(http://www.uniprot.org/terms)
hence it splits there as well and eventually I don’t get the result I want. I tried using regex but was not abler to figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean forward (/) or backward (\) slash? You use both, confusing.

Comment: This in inconsistent you say 1) ends with the character “\” and 2)  another string with “//“ - what is the issue as these are different

Comment: Does it end with \ or //? You say one and show the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regex that only splits on `//` if it's not preceded by `:`

```
import re
myre = re.compile("(?<!:)//")
uniprotFileList = myre.split(uniprotFileContent)
```

Comment: @shabana: You should *accept* this answer by checking it on the left.

Comment: When i run above code, I get 54 (18*3) items in the list rather than 18. It is not affecting my output as it is overwriting the files but I think it would be good to address the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are there empty entries or duplicate entries in the list or something else? Without knowing your data, it's hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: These are the duplicates. So I am using set command to get rid of the duplicates uniprotFileList=list(set(uniprotFileList)). But I am not sure why I am getting these duplicates.

Comment: Can you post a data sample (edit your question, paste it there, select it and press Ctrl-K)? You shouldn't be getting duplicates from `split` unless they already are duplicate in your input.

Comment: Yes, there were duplicates in the file. I should have been more intelligent. But I do get an empty string as an element of list when I split the file. I did check for blank line at the end of the file but there is none. Thanks much!

Comment: Well, if the string ends in `//`, then `split()` returns an empty string as the last element (which is the correct behavior). So you might need to adjust for that case.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the code with modified split pattern and it works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os   
uniprotFile = open("UNIPROT-data.txt")   
uniprotFileContent = uniprotFile.read()
uniprotFileList = uniprotFileContent.split("//\n")
for items in uniprotFileList:
    seqInfoFile = open('%s.dat' % items[5:17], 'w')
    seqInfoFile.write(str(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `\` (backslash) and `/` (slash). You don't need to escape a slash, just use `"/"`. For a backslash, you do need to escape it, so use `"\\"`.

Secondly, if you split with a backslash it will **not** split on a slash or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Split using a regular exception that doesn't permit the "http:" part before your // marker.
For example: "([^:])\/\/"

Comment: That will include the character before `//` in the split, removing it from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be splitting on the wrong characters. Based on your question, you should split on r"\", not "//". Open a prompt and inspect the strings you're using. You'll see something like:

```
>>> "\\"
'\\'
>>> "\"
SyntaxError
>>> r"\"
'\\'
>>> "//"
'//'
```

So, you can use "\" or r"\" (I recommend r"\" for clarity in splitting and regex operations.

Comment: I am sorry it is the forward slash (“\\").